# explain the reaction mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

$\ce{ROH + NaBr + H2SO4 -> RBr + NaHSO4 + H2O}$

What is exactly the reaction mechanism.

Is it $\ce{NaBr + H2SO4 -> NaHSO4 + HBr}$ and then

$\ce{HBr}$ reacts with $\ce{ROH}$?

If yes the why in the reaction of $\ce{NaBr}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$ does $\ce{H2SO4}$ oxidise $\ce{NaBr}$?

Answer (score 3):

> HBr reacts with ROH?

Exactly. It's just a nucleophilic substitution.